# Interpretación e implentación Tensorflow en fórmula de ajuste de pérdida en aprendizaje automático (UDA)

Tags: python, machine-learning

Estoy tratando de comprender una fórmula específica utilizada en un algoritmo de aprendizaje automático, específicamente en el contexto de Unsupervised Domain Adaptation (UDA). La fórmula es la siguiente:

[image: Formula]
En esta fórmula, N_original
​
y N_augmented
se mencionan como "the class frequencies of the predicted class (class with the highest predicted probability)". Mi comprensión inicial de "frecuencia" es la cantidad de veces que se repite una clase, pero en este contexto parece tener un significado diferente.

¿Cómo se definen exactamente  N_original  y  N_augmented  en el contexto de este algoritmo UDA?
¿Qué tipo de información o valores deberían representar estas variables?
¿Cómo interpreto o contextualizo el significado de "frecuencia" en este contexto?

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.